# Echoing a button that uses MySQL to pull data from a database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have an issue with either quotation marks or
 syntax, I'm not entirely sure.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="pagination btn-group" id="items">
                    <? $sql = "SELECT itemname FROM items ORDER BY itemname ASC";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $itemname = $row['itemname'];
                    $price = $row['price'];

                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        echo "<button class='btn btn-medium highlight-color-0' id=$id itemname=$itemname price=$price><div class='btn-image gears'></div><span class='btn-text'>$itemname</span>";
                    }

                    echo "</button>"; ?>
                </div>
```

I then call to this in jQuery using this code:

```
$('.pagination btn-group').click(function()
                    {
                        id = $(this).attr('id');
                        name = $(this).attr('itemname');
                        price = $(this).attr('price');
                    });
```

However, I seem to be getting undefined results? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `$('.pagination btn-group').click(...` should be `$('.pagination .btn').click(...` and when you echo the button wrap the variables in `'` or `"` quotes like: `...id='".$id."' itemname='". $itemname."'...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put the below lines inside while loop

```
$id = $row['id'];
$itemname = $row['itemname'];
$price = $row['price'];
```

should be like

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$itemname = $row['itemname'];
$price = $row['price'];

echo "<button class='btn btn-medium highlight-color-0' id=$id itemname=$itemname price=$price><div class='btn-image gears'></div><span class='btn-text'>$itemname</span>";
}
```